# Qualtrics: Randomly placing a Block in one of only 2 locations in the flow

Tags: design-patterns, qualtrics

I am designing a survey flow in Qualtrics.  I have two blocks items (X and Y) that I would like to randomly place either before or after other other blocks of the survey (A,B,C)
For example, I want exactly one of these two orders-- XYABCD or ABXYCD -- to be randomly assigned to the subjects.

I have randomly assigned questions in a block and randomly included (or omitted) a block, and randomized when a block is included...but I don't see the technique to randomize across one of two locations.

Online help directs me how to

1. randomize whether and where a block appears (random block location),
2. randomize question order in a block,
3. randomize response options to a question, and
4. randomize questions appearing in a block (e.g., treatment v control condition)
5. make a block of questions appear a second time later in the survey

but not randomize a block to appear in only 1 of 2 places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a randomizer and under it set an embedded data field to 1 or 2, evenly displayed. Then add branches to the survey flow to display XY before ABC if 1 or after ABC if 2.